# Is there any 32 bits base image in Azure?

Tags: image, azure, 32-bit, radix

Is there any 32 bits base image to deploy a VM in Azure? (August '19).

This link says that 32 bits are allowed to run (Windows only),
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021388/support-for-32-bit-operating-systems-in-azure-virtual-machines

But I cannot find any 32bit OS base image in the Azure market to deploy (for testing purposes).
I know that I can upload a vhd to Azure based on a existing 32bit OS, but Imagine that I don't have such option.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no 32 bits base image provided in the Azure marketplace. As the link that you post shows, you can bring your own 32 bits image to Azure, but Azure might not offer additional support for them. You need to upload your own 32 bits image to Azure, it's your own duty.

Anyway, I will recommend you use the 64 bits image which Azure marketplace provided. If you really want to use the 32 bits image in Azure, you can create a windows server with virtualization enabled and use the hyper-v technology to run the 32 bits image in it. But finally, you also need to find the 32 bits image yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using a 64 bit image from Azure is not an option in this particular case.